# CircleView Indicator android error (Probably Newbie error)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in android dev and i'm tring to implement a Circle indicator.
I'm following the JakeWharton instruction: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator#usage

But i got an error:

Here is my xml:

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:animationCache="false" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

And my Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //Set the pager with an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)rootView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
  .....
}
```

This line: `pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));`

Give me an error: Non-static method "getSupportFragmentManager()" cannot be referenced from a static context.

I already did the import in the grandle.
How can i fix that? Thanks in advice

--
UPDATE 3:

I did a new NON-STATIC class and now in the new class:

```
//Set the pager with an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        pager.setAdapter(new MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Error: MainActivity is not an enclosing class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use SupportFragmentManager in Fragment you should use the next syntax `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: With that i got this: Cannot resolve symbol "TestAdapter"

Comment: I dunno TestAdapter what is referred to because i dont have any class with that name

Comment: @GMX in that case you should implement one by extending FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: @GMX if answer was correct, please select it as appropriate answer

Comment: Still don't work but now seems close, check my answer in the bottom

Comment: @GMX is it possible that your class is static? check if there are `public class ClassName {` without static word

Comment: public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter, no, i copied the class in the answer by the way

Comment: @GMX what about fragment class?

Comment: @DMX that's what I asking about PlaceholderFragment can't be static. Move it to the separate file and remove **static** word and everything should work properly

Comment: Sorry was off this days, no still don't working =( (i uploaded the answer)

Comment: Why i got all this error? I just created a "Tabbed Activity" from android studio and i'm trying to add the circle indicator... should be really easy

Comment: @GMX it`s hard to say now as I don't have full picture of project structure. Problem should be somewhere there

Comment: With your help and some more modification i did it

Comment: @GMX congratulations))